# Why does this Python 3 code throw EOFError error when run?

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to make a calculator that converts calories, weight, and exercises, to amount of time you need to exercise for my school project. It gives me the error below on the first line that is not a comment.

I need to know why it gives me this error and also how to fix it.

I would also like to know any other errors and how to fix those.

Here is the code:

```
#Imports
#Variables
#Functions
#Game

calories = input("How many calories or what food item ? : ")
weight = input("How much do you weigh? : ")
exercise = input("Enter your exercise or calories burned per pound per minute : ")

if calories < 0 :
    calories = 0
if weight < 0 :
    weight = 0

if exercise == "sitting" :
    exercise = .009
if exercise == "basketball" :
    exercise = .063
if exercise == "walking" :
    exercise = .019
if exercise == "softball" :
    exercise = .0038
if exercise == "weight training" :
    exercise = .039
if exercise == "jogging" :
    exercise = .063
if exercise == "bowling" :
    exercise = .023
if exercise == "fast biking" :
    exercise = .045
if exercise == "swimming" :
    exercise = .064
if exercise == "slow biking" :
    exercise = .029
if exercise == "ice skating" :
    exercise = .53
if exercise == "soccer" :
    exercise = .076
if exercise == "golf" :
    exercise = .033
if exercise == "sitting" :
    exercise = .009
if exercise == "tennis" :
    exercise = .061
if exercise == "jump rope" :
    exercise = .083

if calories == "big mac" :
    calories = 550
if calories == "large fries" :
    calories = 500
if calories == "large coca-cola" :
    calories = 310
if calories == "salad no dressing" :
    calories = 20

answer = calories / (weight * exercise)
minuteanswer = answer
houranswer = 60 / minuteanswer
dayanswer = 24 / houranswer

print("It will take you " + minuteanswer + " minutes, " + houranswer + " hours, or " + dayanswer + " days to burn off those calories with your chosen execise.")

print("TA-DA!!!!!!")
```

Here is the error:

```
How many calories or what food item ? : Traceback (most recent call last):
  Line 6, in <module>
    calories = input("How many calories or what food item ? : ")
EOFError
```

Here is the updated code after fixing all errors:

```
#Imports
#Variables
#Functions
#Game

calories = input("What food item ? : ")
weight = input("How much do you weigh? : ")
exercise = input("Enter your exercise : ")

if exercise == "sitting" :
    exercise = 0.009
elif exercise == "basketball" :
    exercise = 0.063
elif exercise == "walking" :
    exercise = 0.019
elif exercise == "softball" :
    exercise = 0.0038
elif exercise == "weight training" :
    exercise = 0.039
elif exercise == "jogging" :
    exercise = 0.063
elif exercise == "bowling" :
    exercise = 0.023
elif exercise == "fast biking" :
    exercise = 0.045
elif exercise == "swimming" :
    exercise = 0.064
elif exercise == "slow biking" :
    exercise = 0.029
elif exercise == "ice skating" :
    exercise = 0.53
elif exercise == "soccer" :
    exercise = 0.076
elif exercise == "golf" :
    exercise = 0.033
elif exercise == "sitting" :
    exercise = 0.009
elif exercise == "tennis" :
    exercise = 0.061
elif exercise == "jump rope" :
    exercise = 0.083
else :
    exercise = .009

if calories == "big mac" :
    calories = 550.0
elif calories == "large fries" :
    calories = 500.0
elif calories == "large coca-cola" :
    calories = 310.0
elif calories == "salad no dressing" :
    calories = 20.0
else :
    calories = 550

answer = calories / (float(weight) * exercise)
minuteanswer = answer
houranswer = 60 / minuteanswer

print("It will take you " ,minuteanswer ," minutes or " ,houranswer ," hours to burn off those calories with your chosen execise.")

print("TA-DA!!!!!!")
```

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: How are you running this code?  It looks like standard input is closed immediately.

Comment: You think you are using Python 3 but you are not. This error happens when you use Python 2 because `input` automatically tries to `eval` whatever you give it, so if you hit return it gets nothing and produces `EOFError`. Everyone I tell this to swears they are really using Python 3, but I'm always right. You can prove it to yourself by calling `raw_input` instead. This will fix your problem if you are really on Python 2, but cause `NameError` on Python 3. :)

Comment: Are you using an IDE when running the script, or are you launching it via a shell?

Comment: I figured out the error. When I was working on this project at school I didn't have a python IDE, so I had to use an online one. I fixed that error, but I need help with another error:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brady/Desktop/Python Programs/Calorie Calculator.py", line 52, in <module>
    answer = calories / (weight * exercise)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: I removed the part of the code that changes the calories and weight to 0 if they were 0

Comment: it's bad form to re-use variables like you do with exercise and calories. That error is probably caused by the code dropping through all if clauses without a match and not converting the variable to a number type.

Comment: Check and make sure all variables are numbers at the point when you want to do math with them. It's more likely to be the case if the variables used for math have never been anything else than numbers.

Comment: Also, since you figured out the answer to the original question by yourself, you should answer your own question so that this question becomes useful for those that come here because they saw the same error as you did. :)

Comment: I changed all of the if statements after the first one to elifs, and put an else at the end which changes them to 1. I get this error:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Brady/Desktop/Python Programs/Calorie Calculator.py", line 56, in <module>
    answer = calories / (weight * exercise)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: do: print(calories + " / ( " + weight + " * " + exercise + ")" ) to see what is a string. you can coerce variables to numbers with int() and float()

Comment: @BradyW please update the question or make a new one. That way is easier to look at the code and give you an answer

Comment: Because "abc" * 3 = "abcabcabc", multiplying string with integer is valid action. However, you can't multiply "abc" with 1.5 (a float), thus the error that seems unintuitive.

Comment: @Fuu would I do float(weight) and float(calories) to assign the variables and where would I put them in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the original question is that I wasn't using the right IDE and the Python version was 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer your own question and help the community!